# How to avoid .dmp files to be deleted

Tags: windows-server, windows-error-reporting

I am looking for the dump files created after an app crash in Windows Server 2019. I found an application event log entry generated by "Windows Error Reporting". The event contains some paths under "attached files" and "These files my be available here" entries, but no files are in these locations, except by the "report.wer" file.

I was looking for the .dmp files, but they are gone after one hour the event was recorded.

Is there any windows configuration to clean these files up? What should I do to keep them a bit longer in disk?

Answer (score 0):

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/wer-settings.

1. See `LocalDumps\DumpFolder or LocalDumps\[Application Name]\DumpFolder`.
   You could set a local path where crash dumps for your app should be saved.
2. By default only basic parameters of an error report are archived (usually at `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive`).  If you want to archive all data, you could try setting the `ConfigureArchive` WER setting.
   Note: This would lead to archival of all error reports, which might fill your disk quickly.